# How to handle javascript object blob of unknown type

Tags: javascript, websocket, java-websocket

I am trying to do an experiment to stream screen content on an Android device to a remote web browser. I am using web socket to stream the content. I am using this library to implement a websocket server on Android device side: https://github.com/TooTallNate/Java-WebSocket. And I am trying to use HTML canvas on the browser side to receive the content. I am not a javascript programmer but need to write some websocket client code in javascript to receive content from Android device.

On Android side:

```
public void send(byte[] bytes) {
  for (final WebSocket conn : connections) {
     conn.send(bytes);
  }
}
```

Basically it reads screenshots as bitmaps represented by byte[] in Java.

I am using this javascript code on browser to receive the data:

```
document.getElementById("open").onclick = function(evt) {
    if (ws) {
        return false;
    }
    ws = new WebSocket(serverAddr);
    ws.onopen = function(evt) {
        print("OPEN");
    }
    ws.onclose = function(evt) {
        print("CLOSE");
        ws = null;
    }
    ws.onmessage = function(evt) {
        print("RESPONSE: " + evt.data);
        console.log(evt);
    }
    ws.onerror = function(evt) {
        print("ERROR: " + evt.data);
    }
    return false;
};
```

The print method just append strings to a div.

ws.onmessage is indeed invoked. I can see a lot of

```
RESPONSE: [object Blob]
```

printed out in the browser then I am trying to figure out what I actually received in javascript code. So I went to the console and see something like this:

[image]

Then I feel I am hitting a wall: I indeed received some object in javascript because it prints out "object Blob". And it should contain the bitmap data (the size is quite a large number). But that's all the information I can see from the console. How can I process the javascript if I don't know the details about it?

Comment: "Blob" means "Binary Large OBject". That blob is probably an image file. You can probably convert it to a data URL and put it in the `src` of an `img` tag. It is not clear what you are asking though.

Comment: I tried to use javascript to set the blob as the src attribute of an img and it worked.